# Check if my iOS application can be force updated

Tags: app-store, swift5

I have an API which has parameters as version and a success and a failure block. I want to force update the app if we have the version less than the version coming from server. How can we do that? This needs to be done when the user brought the application to the foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't actually force the upgrade, a typical solution here is to provide an alert with a button taking the user to the app's AppStore URL, which will prompt them to update the app. This alert can be triggered on every app launch such that the user cannot get into the app without installing the upgrade.

Comment: How can I trigger this alert and from where should I trigger this alert I am using Scene Delegate in the app. The user needs to be prompted for the alert only when the app is in foreground

Comment: You would connect this via UIScreenDelegate, in sceneWillEnterForeground.

Comment: Yes by writing in sceneWillEnter foreground it worked